# Parameter Substitution with default value: ${1-str} vs ${1-`echo str`}

Tags: bash, shell-script

What's the difference between `${1-default_string_value}` and `` ${1-`echo default_string_value`} ``

Why use the second form over the first one?

Edit:

I have seen the second form used in multiple places, for instance as a relatively wide spread git alias `` abbrev = !sh -c 'git rev-parse --short ${1-`echo HEAD`}' - ``

My gut feeling is that this second form is used by modifying existing (e.g. googled) snippets that do have to use a command as default value, but I could be overlooking something, hence this question.

Comment: Have you ever actually seen `${1:\`echo default_string_value\`}` written somewhere? It makes no sense stand-alone so if you have a script that's doing it and can provide more context then maybe we can explain whatever the real code is doing.

Comment: @EdMorton see my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a functional point of view it makes no difference. It's just less efficient. Some other notes about that code:

- it leaves `` `...` `` and `${1...}` unquoted which means they're subject to split+glob which make no sense here.
- `-` is a poor choice of value of `$0` for that inline script. It would make error messages quite confusing for instance.
- `` `...` `` is the deprecated form of command substitution. `$(...)` is preferred these days though in this specific instance it would make no difference.

Also note that when the command contains shell meta-characters ([`` |&;<>()$`\"' \t\n*?[#~=%" ``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9bc233ae1cf19a49e51842c7959d80a675dbd1c0/run-command.c#L271), including SPC which in the sh language delimits command arguments), then `git` runs a shell to interpret the value of the *alias* with  `"$@"` appended to it. So, here, we end up running `sh -c 'sh -c...'`.

To optimise it further, you could change it to:

```
git config --global alias.abbrev '!
  abbrev() {
    exec git rev-parse --short "${1-HEAD}"
  }
  abbrev'
```

Which saves a few forks and execs.

Comment: Thank you for everything, elegant solution, less is more.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second form to make things slower.

According to `perf` it takes about 3 million clock cycles to run `bash -c 'echo hello'` on my machine. It will hopefully take less than this to do the command substitution but it will still be much more than just having the fixed string.

If `echo` was replaced by something that did rather more, perhaps `id -u` it would provide you with way to override the value from the command. This leads to the second reason for using the second form, it might be for consistency - every other assignment is for overriding a command so here use echo as the command.